# hibernate, transaction timeout

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, ejb

I'm having a rather silly problem but I'm missing the knowledge and tools to track and solve it. Basically I have a long running method that do some computation. Just before this method is started I merge an object that is passes as a parameter to this method, but this object is not modified by it. The merge operation is done by a session facade, so i do something like this:

```
@EJB
private ScenarioFacadeLocal sfl;
@EJB
private ComputationEngineLocal solver;

...

private void longRun() {
   myScenario = sfl.edit(myScenario); // merge
   solver.setScenario(myScenario);
   solver.run();
   // get the solution and persist it
}
```

the solver.run is also an ejb that requires another ejb facade to query the db for some additional info during computation. Let's say that at a certain point it do something like this:

```
visibilityFacade.getSomeInfo, if they are not present into the db, calculate them, add the to the db and give me
```

this method alone is a short running task and can be executed in a single transaction.

The problem is, arjuna kill some transaction due to timeout during solver.run() and I can't understand what transaction is actually killing. What am I doing wrong? what can I use to list me the open transaction and fix it?

Is it possible that it opens a new transaction during the solver.run() for the visiblityFacade and keeps it open for the whole run method and going in timeout?

Comment: Have you closed your previous hibernate session

Comment: I use container managed transaction, so I do not explicitly begin and commit transaction. The point is, I do not know which transaction is causing problem.

Comment: post your full stack-trace